# How to prioritize Fabrication over all else?

Tags: rimworld

How can I prioritize work at the Fabrication bench when I have one main crafter?

They seem to prioritize working at the drug bench, so I added a skill cap to prevent skilled workers from making drugs, but he just moved onto the smelter, which has no such capping ability because it's unskilled labor.

The only way I can think of is to assign specific jobs to individual people, but then I lose some flexibility of being able to take advantage of colonist's down time.

Is there a way to prioritize one crafting job over another? Having to constantly select them and say "Prioritize work on Fabrication Bench" is a pain.

Comment: what you can do is working with restricted arease.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze That's one way. I'm on my fourth colony though, and I've had every colonist I've ever had (except one) on "unrestricted". I rather not restrict them just for that purpose. And this ended up being a non-problem once you get more crafters. I have 2 crafters at ~17, and maybe 5 around 12. Everything's been working out lately.

Comment: I'll add that in the newest version of Rimworld, the Work tab allows much more narrow control if you enable the expanded view. It likely has an option to prioritize certain types of crafting now (although I haven't explicitly checked).

Answer (score 2):

The advanced work distribution scheme allows you to assign priorities. https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Work check the screenshot, there is a cross to the upper left saying "manual priorities" with this enabled you can not only assign who does what, but also set priorities for the individual. Have your best doctor drop everything in case of a medical emergency for example.

Please note that "craft" in this list includes "dumb" labour such as chopping stone blocks, melting metal chunks etc. Drug making also sorts under this category. You'll probably want your most skilled crafter to prioritize skilled crafting like smithing/tailoring over the general crafting. The fabricator/machining table counts as smithing.

Additionally, as you noticed, each work bench comes with its own menu if you click on it. Here you can assign a required skill level for a certain work order, or even set that only a certain character may fill the work order. You can also tell the crafter to just drop the item on the ground when done crafting it, so that your best crafter isn't wasting time putting that item in a stockpile, but immediately goes to grab more material. You can put a high priority stockpile next to the work bench to minimize that as well.

Example:

You want to produce -lots- of high quality leather boots -fast- out of some valuable leather you have stashed. You want your best crafter on the job.

- In the above mentioned work menu, make sure to set your best crafter to prioritize tailoring high.
- Put a leather stockpile next to a tailor bench. In case you don't have lots of space, put a tiny one (1-2 squares) with critical priority next to the workbench. Anyone doing hauling will now keep the stockpile filled up.
- On the workbench, assign a create leather boots task to your best crafter, either to a fixed amount of items or to just do it forever, meaning they'll stop when they run out of material. You can specify the specific material to use, like just use a specific leather type. Tell them to also drop the item on the ground once done, instead of hauling it away.
- Now all haulers will fill up the stockpile with leather as well as carry off the finished goods to where it needs to be, while your best crafter stays put at the tailor bench crafting.